# CUDA Atomic Operations thread or block level?

Tags: cuda, atomic

When occurs an atomic operation serialized at block level? 
If I have the following code :

```
__global__ void sum (int *input){

   if ( threadIdx.x == 0) 
     __shared__ int result = 0;
   __syncthreads(); 
   atomicAdd(result,input[threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockId.x]);
}
```

do this serialization occurs at block level? 
I don't understand in general what "block level serialization" means because from what I know operations are always performed by threads.

Comment: You seem to ask different questions than the one in the title. What is the problem>? atomic operations? understanding of block level serialization? what occurs?

Comment: I would know why an atomic add on a shared variable is a kind of serialization that occurs at block  level and not at thread level.

Comment: Hum I am not sure if that is right (or if I am interpreting it right). Why do you say that its a block-level serialization? where did you get that term from?

Comment: What is "thread level serialization?".  Your choices of parallel execution granularity are warp, block or grid. Threads effectively serial as the basic execution unit on the gpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of atomic operations in CUDA:

- Those that operate on global memory
- Those that operate on shared memory

Global memory is "visible" to all threads in a grid/kernel (i.e. there is only one logical view of global memory, and all threads within a grid share the same view), and therefore global atomics create (as necessary) serialization that is **device-wide**, typically(*) getting resolved in the L2 cache, which is a device-wide resource.

Shared memory is logically a per-threadblock resource (different threadblocks have different logical views of shared memory, ie. their own "private copy" of shared memory) and physically a resource that is per-SM.  Since shared memory is logically a per-threadblock resource, only threads within a particular threadblock have the same "view" or logical copy of shared memory.  Therefore, when performing shared-memory atomics, the "serialization" that may occur is serialization at the threadblock level (as compared to device wide).  Only threads within the same threadblock could be competing for access to a particular shared memory location, because shared memory is logically a separate entity for each threadblock.

Within a single thread, all instructions are logically serialized, and there is no concept of an atomic operation that operates only within a single thread.  atomics operate either (logically) across the threads belonging to a single threadblock or else across all threads in the grid/kernel.

Of course, all atomic operations involve competition between threads for access to a particular location.  The important distinction is whether they are competing for access to a location in shared memory, or a location in global memory.

Syntactically, there is no distinction between a shared memory atomic and a global memory atomic (in CUDA C++, that is; CUDA PTX or SASS is a different situation).  The determination of whether an atomic operation will take place on shared memory or global memory is a function of the type (i.e. numerical value, or else the logical association) of the pointer passed to the atomic that provides the location to update.  If that pointer "points" to shared memory, it is a shared memory atomic.  If that pointer "points" to global memory, it is a global memory atomic.

Atomics are [documented](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions)

(*) recently, the `nvcc` compiler driver picked up the capability to recognize certain atomic patterns that are warp-wide and perform [atomic aggregation](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-optimized-filtering-warp-aggregated-atomics/).  When the compiler chooses this realization, it could be argued that the atomic competition within the warp, when the compiler chooses that idiom, is not getting resolved in the L2 cache.

Comment: I love your footnote about atomic aggregation. That is the first time I hear that from an Nvidia employee. We had been scratching our heads for a while about when the compiler recognizes the pattern and when it doesn't. In the end, we decided to always do the aggregation ourselves, at the risk of the compiler inserting a second, redundant aggregation.

Comment: the indication is already given in the article I linked.  the use of "recently" here is debatable.  I would think that the situation of most threads in the warp not participating in the atomic (presumably the case if you are doing your own aggregation) would be a solid indication to the compiler to not insert an aggregation idiom.  If you find a counterexample, you might consider filing an RFE at developer.nvidia.com to request that the compiler not insert a redundant aggregation idiom.

Comment: Thanks. We had studied that blog post carefully but I think at the time it hadn't been updated yet to mention the compiler now performs the optimization itself. In the end we decided the cost of the redundant aggregation to be negligible compared to the atomic memory accesses (the main benefit would come from smaller code, i.e. potentially being able to fit larger kernels into the instruction cache), so not warranting reaching out to Nvidia.